# Apply CSS styling to a mapped item

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, underscore.js

I have a list of items that are checkboxes for a settings page. These are stored in a `const items` like so:

```
const ITEMS = [
    ["youtube", "YouTube"],
    ["videos", "Videos"],
    ["facebook", "Facebook"],
    ["settings", "Settings"],
]
```

and currently, these four items are just listed as list items. What I have right now is this:

[image]

but what I want is this:

[image]

I was thinking of applying a check to see if the sub-category belongs to that parent category, and apply some type of indentation to the sub-categories. Is that possible to do through a `map` (which is how I'm iterating through this array)? Or is there a smarter, more efficient way to solve this issue?

Here's how I render my checkboxes:

```
item: function(i) {
    return (
        <div className="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.items[i[0]]}/>
                {i[1]}
            </label>
        </div>
    )
}

render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="col-sm-12">
            {_(ITEMS).map(this.item, this)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you post some Code how you generate the Checkboxes? And I wonder why you're using sub-arrays as items in an array...?

Comment: I used an array within an array to access the value "youtube", "videos", etc. for when it's checked, and it displays "YouTube" properly on the site. Should I switch to an object that contains each array instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use objects in an array. So you're able to map more than just property to each item. For accessing it only with normal Javascript I would use a `for`-Loop because of its compability with older browsers. An example I made, can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/morrisjdev/vjb0qukb/

Comment: The fiddle, specifically the `var items` struct, helped me a bunch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With some 'dirty' code, you could use this: https://jsfiddle.net/1sw1uhan/

```js
const ITEMS = [
    ["youtube", "YouTube"],
    ["videos", "Videos"],
    ["facebook", "Facebook"],
    ["settings", "Settings"],
]

var list = $('<ul>');
$.each(ITEMS, function( index, value ) {
 if ((index+1)%2 == 0 && index != 0){
  var sublist = $('<ul>').append($('<li>').text(value[1]).attr('id', value[0]));
 } else {
  var sublist = $('<li>').text(value[1]).attr('id', value[0]);
 }
 list.append(sublist);
})
$('#somediv').append(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="somediv">

</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other solution that doesn't involve jQuery? This seems a little too messy for my liking, but I do appreciate the answer.

Comment: Do you have four items every time or is the list dynamic?

Comment: It'll be a static list of ITEMS, so should be easier to deal with.

Comment: I've got no easier idea, than the code above. Are you using plain JS?

Comment: I'm using React/JSX, and this is company code so I don't wish to introduce jQuery into this. It's not the end of the world, I was just wondering if this could be done in an easy way. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Because you have a normal list and a sublist, you need an for-loop, which contains an modulo-case. With this option, you can switch between both lists real easy. If someone has a better idea, please feel free. (So you just have to switch my jQuery snippet into React.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121286/discussion-between-homerboy-and-tobias-k).